# Pair unique pairs in the same column by same key with map/reduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm using a Mongo map reduce operation.

Here is a sample of my db agents:

```
{
"agent_id": 1,
"first": "Nick",
"last": "Black",
"address": "44 1st Avenue",
"city": "Athens",
"country": "USA",
"salary": 50553,
"languages": ["Hebrew", "Japanese"],
"security_clearance" :{
    "sec_id": 5,
    "sec_level": "Secret",
    "description": "Fifth highest level of access"
    }
}
```

I am trying to find pairs of agents who live in the same city. Remove duplicate pairs in your result. I also need to use a **mapReduce** for this. The output would look like this:

```
"results" : [
    {
            "_id" : "Athens",
            "value" : {
                    "result" : [
                            {
                                    "agent1_first" : "Nick",
                                    "agent1_last" : "Black",
                                    "agent2_first" : "Jim",
                                    "agent2_last" : "Smith"
                            }
                    ]
            }
    },
    {
            "_id" : "New York",
            "value" : {
                    "result" : [
                            {
                                    "agent1_first" : "Mathew",
                                    "agent1_last" : "Cohen",
                                    "agent2_first" : "Bill",
                                    "agent2_last" : "Heeman"
                            }
                    ]
            }
    }
],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility, starting from a [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage:

```
// { agent: "Nick Black",   salary: 50553, city: "Athens" }
// { agent: "John Doe",     salary: 43034, city: "Athens" }
// { agent: "Jim Smith",    salary: 63489, city: "Athens" }
// { agent: "Mathew Cohen", salary: 56345, city: "Paris"  }
db.agents.aggregate([
  { $lookup: {
    from: "agents",
    localField: "city",
    foreignField: "city",
    as: "agents"
  }},
  { $unwind: "$agents" },
  { $set: {
    agent2: "$agents.agent",
    salary2: "$agents.salary",
    agents: {
      $cond: {
        if: { $gt: ["$agent", "$agents.agent"] },
        then: ["$agent", "$agents.agent"],
        else: ["$agents.agent", "$agent"]
      }
    }
  }},
  { $group: {
    _id: "$agents",
    x: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { $match: { $expr: {
    $ne: [
      { $first: "$x.agents" },
      { $last: "$x.agents" }
    ]
  }}},
  { $replaceWith: "$x" },
  { $unset: ["_id", "agents"] }
])
// { agent: "Nick Black", salary: 50553, city: "Athens", agent2: "John Doe",  salary2: 43034 }
// { agent: "Nick Black", salary: 50553, city: "Athens", agent2: "Jim Smith", salary2: 63489 }
// { agent: "John Doe",   salary: 43034, city: "Athens", agent2: "Jim Smith", salary2: 63489 }
```

---

We first join the `agents` collection with itself on the `city` field with a `$lookup` stage. This gives us rows with an agent and agents sharing their city:

```
{
  agent: "Nick Black",
  salary: 50553,
  city: "Athens",
  agents: [
    { agent: "Nick Black", salary: 50553, city: "Athens" }, 
    { agent: "John Doe", salary: 43034, city: "Athens" },
    { agent: "Jim Smith", salary: 63489, city: "Athens" }
  ] 
}
```

We then [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) (explode) the list of agents for a given agent, such that the document just above becomes 3 documents:

```
{ agent: "Nick Black", salary: 50553, city: "Athens", agents: { agent: "Nick Black", salary: 50553, city: "Athens" } }
{ agent: "Nick Black", salary: 50553, city: "Athens", agents: { agent: "John Doe", salary: 43034, city: "Athens" } }
{ agent: "Nick Black", salary: 50553, city: "Athens", agents: { agent: "Jim Smith", salary: 63489, city: "Athens" } }
```

The following `$set` stage's main role is to create an identifier for the agent1-agent2 tuple, such that we can latter group them to distinct them. This also means sorting agent1, and agent2 such that the ordering of this tuple is always the same.

Follows the `$group` stage that distinct rows by their pair of agents. The distinct is made by getting the `$first` document from a group.

The `$match` stage that follows excludes documents whose agent pair is made of the same agent.

And the final `$replaceWith` and `$unset` stages are there to clean-up the result.

Comment: I needed to use a mapReduce for this, how would I do that?

Comment: I missed that part. Note that mongo's map/reduce has been deprecated starting in `Mongo 5` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/)

Comment: I understand but I need to use that for this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.agents.mapReduce( 
   function() { emit(this.city,this); }, 
   function(key, values) {
  var val = [];
  for(var i=0;i<values.length-1;i++) { 
      for(var j=i+1;j<values.length;j++) {
    val.push({
        "agent1_first" : values[i].first,
        "agent1_last" : values[i].last,
        "agent2_first" : values[j].first,
        "agent2_last" : values[j].last
     });
    }
  } 
  return val;
}, {  
      out: { inline: 1 }
   }
);
```

mapReduce accepts plain Javascript functions. In the map function , we pass each object based on city.

In reduce , we iterate the list of agents in each city and frame the non duplicate elements and return the value to inline printing